# A HTML page doesn't display right in a QWebview

Tags: html, css, qt, qwebview

I'm doing a little software that has a `QWebView`to display `HTML`files. My problem is that my welcome page doesn't display well. It looks like [image: this] when it should have an image between those red lines, in the center. The problem is surely my `HTML`and/or `CSS. So here is my`HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles/accueil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="ligne">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="ligne">&nbsp;</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

And my `CSS`:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background-color:white;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:100%;
}

img{
    border:none;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
    background-image: url(../icones/accueil.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}

.ligne{
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:#ee1b2e;
}
```

Any idea of what I wrote wrong?

Thanks!

------EDIT------

There's only on XP that happen...on MAC, 7 and Vista it works find. It should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/86u6G/)

Comment: else if someone has another way to make a page like that I would try it! I'm not that good in HTML CSS so I'm opened mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why, but the problem was my image...I needed to have a .png image instead of a .jpg

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is when you using program with qwebview on computer where Qt doesn't installed. If so, add to program directory folder [imageformats]. Just copy it from Qtdir. By default Qt supports *.png and *.svg formats, for *.jpg and other formats that set of dll is necessary for windows.